# USB 2.0 ports stop working, USB 3.0 port OK

Tags: windows-8, usb-3, usb-2

I have a Windows 8 laptop (Acer V3-551-8489) that features 1 USB 3.0 port and 2 USB 2.0 ports. For some reason, the USB 2.0 ports stop working from time to time.

Is there a way to restart those ports? Or a fix?

Comment: Similar questions (but without any answers): *[USB 3 works, USB 2/1 doesn't work. The Root Hub reports "HubIs2xCapable: 0 (Is not 2.x capable)"](https://superuser.com/questions/1720659/)* and *[USB 1.0/2.0 stopped working, but USB 3.0+ still works. Acer laptop, Windows 11/Linux Mint](https://superuser.com/questions/1708882/)*