# USB 1.0/2.0 stopped working, but USB 3.0+ still works. Acer laptop, Windows 11/Linux Mint

Tags: usb, drivers, hardware-failure, usb-3, firmware

The laptop is a 2017 Acer Spin 5 SP515-51GN, which internally is the same as a Nitro Spin NP515-51.

The laptop has three USB-A ports, and one USB-C port. Edit for clarity: all ports are USB 3. No dedicated USB 2 ports.

**Symptom: All USB 3.0+ (SuperSpeed) devices work, including through daisy-chained USB 3 hubs, connected by USB A or C. However, USB 1/2 device or hub is not detected. No more clickity-clackety keyboard or fancy sound card :(** No identifiable cause or significant event preceding the failure. Same symptoms in Windows 11 and Linux Mint.

Image 1: USB Device Tree Viewer with a USB 3.0 Kingston flash drive connected through two USB 3 hubs. A USB 2.0 flash drive is also connected but not detected. (The other devices shown are the laptop's built-in hardware (keyboard etc.). Note: F=full speed=USB 1, H=high speed=USB 2, S=superspeed=USB 3. The built-in hardware functions normally - apparently over full-speed and high-speed connections?)

[image: USB Device Tree Viewer with a USB 3.0 Kingston flash drive connected through two USB 3 hubs. A USB 2.0 flash drive is also connected but not detected.]

Image 2: Could these highlighted lines be a clue? Is "HubIs2.xCapable" a flag which can be changed in the firmware/driver?

[image: USB hub specifications]

Attempted fixes:

- Windows System Restore to a time before the problem began
- uninstalled and reinstalled the USB root hub driver through Windows Device Manager

Further symptoms/info:

- One of the USB-A ports no longer works at all. Originally two of the ports had stopped working, but then one of them returned to life, for no clear reason.
- I have previously taken apart the laptop to clean out dust, so I can't rule out mechanical damage. However, the USB ports are soldered directly onto the motherboard, ruling out a loose connector.

Here's the hardware/controller info. If necessary, I might (perhaps) be able to find a screenshot this info from before the failure.

```
    ========================== My Computer ==========================
Operating System       : Windows 10 Home: NT10.0 Build 22000.556 Version 2009 SP0 type=1 suite=300 x64
Computer Name          : S22
Admin Privileges       : yes

UsbTreeView Version    : 3.7.2.0 (x64)

USB Host Controllers   : 1
USB Root Hubs          : 1
USB Standard Hubs      : 0
USB Peripheral Devices : 4
```

```
===================== USB Host Controller =======================

        +++++++++++++++++ Device Information ++++++++++++++++++
Friendly Name            : Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)
Device Description       : USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller
Device Path              : \\?\PCI#VEN_8086&DEV_9D2F&SUBSYS_12341025&REV_21#3&11583659&0&A0#{3abf6f2d-71c4-462a-8a92-1e6861e6af27} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HOST_CONTROLLER)
Kernel Name              : \Device\NTPNP_PCI0003
Device ID                : PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9D2F&SUBSYS_12341025&REV_21\3&11583659&0&A0
Vendor                   : Intel
Hardware IDs             : PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9D2F&SUBSYS_12341025&REV_21 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9D2F&SUBSYS_12341025 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9D2F&CC_0C0330 PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9D2F&CC_0C03
Driver KeyName           : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0000 (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
Driver                   : \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\USBXHCI.SYS (Version: 10.0.22000.469  Date: 2022-01-28)
Driver Inf               : C:\WINDOWS\inf\usbxhci.inf
Legacy BusType           : PCIBus
Class                    : USB
Class GUID               : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000} (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
Service                  : USBXHCI
Enumerator               : PCI
Location Info            : PCI bus 0, device 20, function 0
Manufacturer Info        : Generic USB xHCI Host Controller
Capabilities             : 0x00 (-)
Status                   : 0x0180000A (DN_DRIVER_LOADED, DN_STARTED, DN_NT_ENUMERATOR, DN_NT_DRIVER)
Problem Code             : 0
Address                  : 1310720 (0x140000)
HcDisableSelectiveSuspend: 0
EnableSelectiveSuspend   : 0
SelectiveSuspendEnabled  : 0
EnhancedPowerMgmtEnabled : 0
IdleInWorkingState       : 1
WakeFromSleepState       : 0
Power State              : D0 (supported: D0, D3, wake from D3)
 Child Device 1          : USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
  Device Path            : \\?\USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&20cdc8ed&1&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB)
  Kernel Name            : \Device\USBPDO-0
  Device ID              : USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&20CDC8ED&1&0
  Class                  : USB
  Driver KeyName         : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0001 (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
  Service                : USBHUB3
  LocationPaths          : PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)#USBROOT(0)  ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(XHC_)#ACPI(RHUB)

        --------------- USB Hostcontroller Info0 --------------
PciVendorId              : 0x8086 (Intel)
PciDeviceId              : 0x9D2F
PciRevision              : 0x21
NumberOfRootPorts        : 0x0C (12 Ports)
ControllerFlavor         : 0x00 (0 = USB_HcGeneric)
HcFeatureFlags           : 0x08
 Port Power Switching    : no
 Selective Suspend       : no
 Legacy BIOS             : no

Roothub Symbolic Link    : USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&20cdc8ed&1&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8}

        ----------- USB Hostcontroller BusStatistics ----------
DeviceCount              : 0x05 (5)
CurrentSystemTime        : 0x01D833A051FD1A0F (2022-03-09 11:27:47)
CurrentUsbFrame          : 0x4422E6 (4465382)
BulkBytes                : 0x00 (0)
IsoBytes                 : 0x00 (0)
InterruptBytes           : 0x00 (0)
ControlDataBytes         : 0x00 (0)
PciInterruptCount        : 0x01 (1)
HardResetCount           : 0x00 (0)
WorkerSignalCount        : 0x00 (0)
CommonBufferBytes        : 0x00 (0)
WorkerIdleTimeMs         : 0x00 (0)
RootHubEnabled           : 0x01 (yes)
RootHubDevicePowerState  : 0x00 (D0)
Unused                   : 0x00 (0)
NameIndex                : 0x00 (0)


        ------ USB Hostcontroller Driver Version Params -------
DriverTrackingCode       : 0x04
USBDI_Version            : 0x600
USBUSER_Version          : 0x04
CheckedPortDriver        : 0x00
CheckedMiniportDriver    : 0x00
USB_Version              : 0x00

        ---------- USB Hostcontroller Bandwidth Info ----------
DeviceCount              : 0x00000000 (0)
TotalBusBandwidth        : 0x0006D600 (448000 bits/ms = 56 MB/s)
Total32secBandwidth      : 0x00DAC000 (14336000 bits/32ms = 56 MB/s)
AllocedBulkAndControl    : 0x002BC000 (2867200 bits/32ms = 11.200 MB/s = 20%)
AllocedIso               : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_1ms     : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_2ms     : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_4ms     : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_8ms     : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_16ms    : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)
AllocedInterrupt_32ms    : 0x00000000 (0 bits/32ms)


        -------- USB Hostcontroller Power States Info ---------
SystemState              : S0    S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    
HcDevicePowerState       : D0    --    --    D3    D3    --    
HcDeviceWake             : D3    D3    D3    D3    D3    D3    
HcSystemWake             : S3    S3    S3    S3    S3    S3    
RhDevicePowerState       : --    D3    D3    D2    D2    --    
RhDeviceWake             : D2    D2    D2    D2    D2    D2    
RhSystemWake             : S4    S4    S4    S4    S4    S4    
LastSystemSleepState     : --    --    --    --    --    --    
CanWakeup                : no    no    no    yes   no    no    
IsPowered                : no    no    no    yes   no    no
```

```
========================= USB Root Hub =========================
Sum of Hubs and Devices  : 4
Sum of Endpoints         : 17

        +++++++++++++++++ Device Information ++++++++++++++++++
Device Description       : USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)
Device Path              : \\?\USB#ROOT_HUB30#4&20cdc8ed&1&0#{f18a0e88-c30c-11d0-8815-00a0c906bed8} (GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB)
Kernel Name              : \Device\USBPDO-0
Device ID                : USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&20CDC8ED&1&0
Hardware IDs             : USB\ROOT_HUB30&VID8086&PID9D2F&REV0021 USB\ROOT_HUB30&VID8086&PID9D2F USB\ROOT_HUB30
Driver KeyName           : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}\0001 (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
Driver                   : \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\UsbHub3.sys (Version: 10.0.22000.65  Date: 2021-12-19)
Driver Inf               : C:\WINDOWS\inf\usbhub3.inf
Legacy BusType           : PNPBus
Class                    : USB
Class GUID               : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000} (GUID_DEVCLASS_USB)
Service                  : USBHUB3
Enumerator               : USB
Location Info            : -
Manufacturer Info        : (Standard USB HUBs)
Capabilities             : 0x80 (SurpriseRemovalOK)
Status                   : 0x0180000A (DN_DRIVER_LOADED, DN_STARTED, DN_NT_ENUMERATOR, DN_NT_DRIVER)
Problem Code             : 0
Address                  : 0
HcDisableSelectiveSuspend: 0
EnableSelectiveSuspend   : 0
SelectiveSuspendEnabled  : 0
EnhancedPowerMgmtEnabled : 0
IdleInWorkingState       : 1
WakeFromSleepState       : 0
Power State              : D0 (supported: D0, D2, D3, wake from D0, wake from D2)

        ------------------- USB Hub Descriptor -----------------
bDescriptorLength        : 0x09 (9 bytes)
bDescriptorType          : 0x29 (Hub Descriptor)
bNumberOfPorts           : 0x12 (18 Ports)
wHubCharacteristics      : 0x0000
 Power switching         : Ganged
 Compound device         : No
 Over-current protection : Global
 TT Think Time           : At most 8 FS bit times
 Port Indicators         : Not supported
bPowerOnToPowerGood      : 0x02 (4 ms)
bHubControlCurrent       : 0x00 (0 mA)
*!*ERROR  Descriptor too short: DeviceRemovable needs 3 bytes to hold 1+18 bits
*!*ERROR  Descriptor too short: PortPwrCtrlMask needs 3 bytes to hold 18 bits
Data (HexDump)           : 09 29 12 00 00 02 00 00 00                        .).......
HubIsBusPowered          : 0x00 (Self Powered)

      ---------------- Extended USB Hub Descriptor ---------------
HubType                  : 0x01 (UsbRootHub - a root hub)
HighestPortNumber        : 0x12 (18 Ports)

        ----------------- USB Hub Capabilities ----------------
HubIs2xCapable           : 0 (Is not 2.x capable)
Data (HexDump)           : 00 00 00 00                                       ....

        --------------- USB Hub Capabilities Ex ---------------
HighSpeedCapable         : 0 (No)
HighSpeed                : 1 (Yes)
MultiTtCapable           : 0 (No)
HubIsMultiTt             : 0 (No)
ArmedWakeOnConnect       : 0 (No)
IsBusPowered             : 0 (No)
IsRoot                   : 1 (Yes)
Data (HexDump)           : 12 00 00 00                                       ....
```

Comment: Questions, mainly out of curiosity: (1) how is the built-in hardware (keyboard, webcam, etc.) still working, if it's connected over full-speed/high-speed USB? (2) From where is the "USB Host Controller" and "USB Root Hub" text derived? Driver, firmware, hardware? Does it live on my SSD or in the motherboard/USB hardware? Is it mutable?

Comment: If USB ports are damaged then it could be that there is dirt or something has bent the pins and is shorting the USB 2 pins together, that could kill communications...

Comment: When hardware works intermittently, it's usually indicative of a hardware issue, which could be with the port itself _(internals pins or pins soldered to the motherboard, incl. anchor feet, which often are ground points to the motherboard)_ or a motherboard component _(albeit this is highly unlikely unless the motherboard experienced a high-G fall or power surge)_. To rule out the ports themselves, test voltage and resistance with a multimeter _(google for the correct voltage/resistance values)_

Comment: If they're dead on both Linux and Windows, that's a hardware failure. Workaround: us a powered USB hub from the working USB 3.0 sockets. USB 3.0 is fully backwards compatible with USB 2.0, so you lose nothing -- unless the PC won't boot from a USB flash drive on a 3.0 port, which you could test.

Comment: That's the thing - it's not backwards compatible here. I have only USB 3.0 sockets, and they don't work for USB 2.0.

Comment: Question: can USB SuperSpeed work without the original/legacy data pins (D+/D-)? (USB 3 adds two additional pairs for data transfer.)

Comment: Yes, SS does work independently of D+/D-.  Question: do you have VBUS active 5V on Type-A ports?

Comment: I checked and the answer is interesting. There are three USB A ports; their VBUS voltages are 5.0V, 3-4V, and 0V. The "3-4V" one's voltage sagged as I daisy-chained USB testers. // All ports have 0V in the D+/D- pins.

Comment: Given that the built in devices work, I guess this means that the root USB controller works, and there's a failure downstream of it. How crazy an idea is it to open the computer, cut the webcam wires, lead them out through the fan holes, and connect them to a USB hub?

Comment: Similar questions (but without any answers): *[USB 3 works, USB 2/1 doesn't work. The Root Hub reports "HubIs2xCapable: 0 (Is not 2.x capable)"](https://superuser.com/questions/1720659/)* and *[USB 2.0 ports stop working, USB 3.0 port OK](https://superuser.com/questions/583593/)*