# USB 3 works, USB 2/1 doesn't work. The Root Hub reports "HubIs2xCapable: 0 (Is not 2.x capable)"

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, firmware, usb-2

The USB ports on my laptop only work with USB 3.x devices, but not USB 1/2. I've confirmed with a multimeter that the DATA+/DATA- pins are silent, even when talking to a USB 3.0 drive.

What could cause that?

- Driver: no, it's the same in Windows and Linux Mint.
- Hardware: perhaps; hopefully not.
- Firmware: maybe? That's what I'm here to figure out.

In USB Tree Viewer, **I see a report for USB 3.0 Root Hub which says "HubIs2xCapable: 0 (Is not 2.x capable)". But USB 2.0 used to work, so presumably this used to be "1 (Is 2.x capable)"?**

The key question is:

- Theoretically: was this flag changed, causing USB 2.x to be disabled? Or did the hardware fail, causing the flag to be changed?
- Experimentally: **Can I flip that flag from 0 to 1, and see if it re-enables my USB 2.x?**

[image: HubIs2xCapable: 0 (Is not 2.x capable)]

Where is this information from? (hardware's ROM, firmware, Windows driver?) How can I view it (edit it?) outside of this USB Tree View software?

Just a footnote: I'm not sure how the above report above can jibe with this one below, which shows that the built-in webcam (which still works) uses USB 2.0.
[image: built-in webcam's report]

Hardware details etc. can be found in my previous post: [USB 1.0/2.0 stopped working, but USB 3.0+ still works. Acer laptop, Windows 11/Linux Mint](https://superuser.com/questions/1708882/usb-1-0-2-0-stopped-working-but-usb-3-0-still-works-acer-laptop-windows-11-l?noredirect=1#comment2633980_1708882)

Comment: (If this isn't fixable, my next question will be whether it's possible to connect USB 2.0 devices over USB 3.0/HDMI pins...which sounds like a pain at best)

Comment: A SuperSpeed (logical) port cannot do USB 2.0/1.1. However, different ports can. It’s the first 12 in your screenshot, with the “H” icon. // You can easily rule out software by using a Live Linux USB/CD/DVD.

Comment: I see - so two logical ports share the same physical port. But, in the first screenshot, it is not a port that I've selected - it's the USB Root Hub. // Yes, I have ruled out software using Linux.

Comment: What the root hub says appears to be irrelevant. It’s the same for me and I have lots of USB 2.0 devices.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the info. Guess I've got a hardware failure then....

Comment: Yes, you do have a hardware failure, since all internally-connected devices do work. I suspect you have fried VBUS power to external ports.

Comment: Does it work while in the BIOS (connecting an external keyboard to a USB 2 port)? I have a similar problem with a GA-970A-DS3P motherboard (both USB 3 ports work, but none of the six USB 2 ports, at least in Linux). The USB 2 ports do work fine for the BIOS with an USB external keyboard, both to break into the BIOS (pressing key "Del" at the right moment for that BIOS) and to navigate and change options while in the BIOS. Thus in my case it ***doesn't*** appear to be a ***hardware*** problem.

Comment: Enabling IOMMU in the BIOS reverses the problem: Now USB 2.0 ports work, but USB 3.0 ports don't. The fix described in *[GA-970A-DS3P revision 1 no USB 3.0](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370)* is supposed to fix the problem in Linux.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you!

Comment: I have now written [a blog post](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/07/20/enabling-both-usb-3-and-usb-2-ports-for-a-ga-970a-ds3p-motherboard/) about it. It is essentially the mentioned blog post, but with some more detail and more explanations. The fix worked (and was positively required) for [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa). Though Fedora 36 (the KDE spin) didn't need it and worked out of the box.

Comment: Some progress?.

Comment: Oh my goodness! I didn't see your reply before. Excellent blog post. I'll look into it, but I'm currently booting pure Windows, so I would have to either repartition or boot from USB to get into GRUB. Before I think about that: would the IOMMU diagnosis fit if my computer's USB 2 was working just fine for several years? Perhaps the IOMMU got disabled somehow?